# Sed expression doesn't allow optional grouped string

Tags: regex, sed

I'm trying to use the following regex in a `sed` script but it doesn't work:

```
sed -n '/\(www\.\)\?teste/p'
```

The regex above doesn't seem to work. `sed` doesn't seem to apply the `?` to the grouped `www\.`.

It works if you use the `-E` parameter that switches `sed` to use the Extended Regex, so the syntax becomes:

```
sed -En '/(www\.)?teste/p'
```

This works fine but I want to run this script on a machine that doesn't support the `-E` operator. I'm  pretty sure that this is possible and I'm doing something very stupid.

Comment: are you using '/' as your regexp divider? I don't see it in your first example, only at the end. Also '/ p' (the space there), might cause many sed's to blow up. And it is the '&' char that plays back what is found inside of \( \) pairs. Maybe I don't understand what you are attempting. Good luck.

Comment: I fixed the starting `/`. It was a copy paste problem. The space doesn't affect me, but I'm now following your suggestion. What I'm  trying to do is match any string that contains the grouped `www\.` or not.

Comment: Have read you posting again. I'm almost sure older seds don't support `'?'` on `(..\)` groupings. Also, I don't think escaping it as `\?` is helping. More helpfully, I hope, recall that you can have multi targets in one /regex/ , so try `'/\(www\.\)teste|teste/p'` . Good luck.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting. It seems that sed doesn't support it. But I was not sure, I couldn't find a resource that shows it. Your solution may work for this simple example but it's a problem if you have larger expressions.

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Standard `sed` only understands POSIX [Basic Regular Expressions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html) (BRE), not Extended Regular Expressions (ERE), and the `?` is a metacharacter in EREs, but not in BREs.

Your version of `sed` might support EREs if you turn them on.  With GNU `sed`, the relevant options are `-r` and `--regexp-extended`, described as "use extended regular expressions in the script".

However, if your `sed` does not support it - quite plausible - then you are stuck.  Either import a version of `sed` that does support them, or redesign your processing.  Maybe you should use `awk` instead.

---

#### 2014-02-21

I don't know why I didn't mention that even though `sed` does not support the shorthand `?` or `\?` notation, it does support counted ranges with `\{n,m\}`, so you can simulate `?` with `\{0,1\}`:

```
sed -n '/\(www\.\)\{0,1\}teste/p' << EOF
http://www.tested.com/
http://tested.com/
http://www.teased.com/
EOF
```

which produces:

```
http://www.tested.com/
http://tested.com/
```

Tested on Mac OS X 10.9.1 Mavericks with the standard BSD `sed` and with GNU `sed` 4.2.2.

Comment: You're right, that's exactly what I was suspecting, just wanted confirmation. There's not a lot of info out here about BRE's.

Comment: sed support ERE's on BSD (option `-E`) and on Linux/Cygwin with (`-r`). On some older Unix systems though there's no ERE, and you're stuck with BRE

Comment: I finally found a good doc that describes the lack of `?` http://www.scribd.com/doc/51950177/280/POSIX-Basic-Vs-Extended-Regular-Expressions

Comment: Added +1 for counted ranges!  Also `-E` works on Mac (highly morphed BSD) too.  Thanks!

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm.