# regex expression that matches phrase, unless its already prefixed

Tags: regex, sed

I'm cleaning up a large C++ code base where I need all variables of type "vector" need to be changed to "std::vector".  Skipping over #include  and comments in the code.  And most importantly, if the expression is already written as "std::vector", don't convert it to "std::std::vector"

That is:

```
#include <vector>
vector<Foo> foolist;
typedef vector<Foo> FooListType;
std::vector<Foo> otherfoolist;
int main()
{
    // this vector is for iteration
    for (vector <Foo>::iterator itor = foo.begin...)
```

Converts to

```
#include <vector>
std::vector<Foo> foolist;
typedef std::vector<Foo> FooListType;
std::vector<Foo> otherfoolist;
int main()
{
    // this vector is for iteration
    for (std::vector<Foo>::iterator itor = foo.begin...)
```

So far, I have this narrowed down to two sed commands

```
sed -r 's/vector\s{0,1}</std::vector</g' < codefile > tmpfile
sed 's/std::std/std/' < tmpfile > codefile
```

The first sed matches "vector< and "vector <" and converts either to "std::vector<".

The second sed fixes the side effect of converting "std::vector<" into "std::std::vector<".

How can merge the two different regex expressions above so I can have a single sed command that fixes the code correctly.

I've tried reading online about lookahead and lookbehind, but my eyes are starting to burn out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the first regexp also match a possible `std::` by using

```
sed -r 's/[std:]*vector\s{0,1}</std::vector</' < codefile > tmpfile
```

btw: you can make the changes in place by adding `-i` and just passing the file as command line parameter:

```
sed -i -r 's/[std:]*vector\s{0,1}</std::vector</' codefile
```

Comment: Thanks. This should work.  One quick note - this will also match other things like "t::vector<" and "tds::vector<".  None of which will likely appear in the codebase, but I'm wondering if there's another way to isolate and skip over a literal "std::".

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i 's/\(^\|[^<:]\)\(vector\s*<\)/\1std::\2/g' file
```

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate on the internals of the first capture expression: \(^\|[^<:]\)\ ?

Comment: @selbie it's a alternation between either start of line or a character which is neither a `<` or `:`.

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I want to filter out out <. That works for #include lines, but not for lines such as "map<vector<foo>> foomap;"

Answer (score 1):

If your sed version does not support extended regular expressions, you can use perl:

`perl -lane ' if (!/^\s*#include/) {s!(?:std::)?vector!std::vector!g;} print; ' < codefile > tmpfile`

this will work in cases like this:  `vector<vector<Foo>> otherfoolist;`

see this answer also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6157705/390913