# Including optional character in regex with sed

Tags: sed

I have the following strings:

```
setenv run_area1 root/test1/Apr14_2019_10_32_39/dummy
setenv area2 root/test2/Aug23_2017_14_25_56/dummy
setenv run_area3 testRun/test1/blue_Apr14_2019_08_56_48/dummy/
setenv area4 testRun/test2/Aug23_2017_14_26_03/thing2
```

I want to replace the Date with `[DATE]` as following:

```
setenv run_area1 root/test1/[DATE]/dummy
setenv area2 root/test2/[DATE]/dummy
setenv run_area3 testRun/test1/blue[DATE]/dummy/
setenv area4 testRun/test2/[DATE]/thing2
```

I have to use sed so I wrote the following command:

```
sed 's|[A-Z][a-z]*[0-9]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*|[DATE]|g'
```

It works good for the strings but for the following one:

```
setenv run_area3 testRun/test1/blue_Apr14_2019_08_56_48/dummy/
```

I get:

```
setenv run_area3 testRun/test1/blue_[DATE]/dummy/
```

I'm looking for a way to use the `_` in the regex. In perl I know that I can use something like `(_|)` so `_` is optional. Also I could use `?`.
For previous threads I saw that the basic `sed` does not includes those options and I need to use the `\{0,1\}`. ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156259/sed-expression-doesnt-allow-optional-grouped-string)).
The problem is, I can't seem to understand how `\{0,1\}` solves it. Are there other solutions?

Comment: Don't have time to test, but I would expect `'s|_*[A-Z][a-z]*[0-9]*.......|....|` to work. good luck.

Answer (score 2):

`\{0,1\}` in a BRE is a regexp interval that means `0 to 1 repetitions of the preceding expression` which is the same as `?` means in an ERE (technically in an ERE it's defined as `0 _or_ 1` but that's the same set of values!) i.e. that the preceding expression is optional.

With any POSIX sed:

```
$ sed 's/_\{0,1\}[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*[0-9]*\(_[0-9]*\)\{4\}/[DATE]/' file
setenv run_area1 root/test1/[DATE]/dummy
setenv area2 root/test2/[DATE]/dummy
setenv run_area3 testRun/test1/blue[DATE]/dummy/
setenv area4 testRun/test2/[DATE]/thing2
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `sed` uses the `basic regular expression` by [default](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Sed#Regular_expressions). For the difference between `basic regular expression` and `extended regular expression`, please refer to this [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html).

If you want to use features supported by `extended regular expression`. You have to tell sed **explicitly** with the `-r` option.

So with **GNU sed** the scripts below do the same thing actually.

```
sed 's|_\?[A-Z][a-z]*[0-9]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*|[DATE]|g' textfile

sed -r 's|_?[A-Z][a-z]*[0-9]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*_[0-9]*|[DATE]|g' textfile
```

Answer (score 0):

If the month and data follows `MMMDD` format, you could consider such an expression unique in the record and base your entire script on that assumption. Somewhat like below:

```
sed -E 's/^(.*)([[:alpha:]]{3}[[:digit:]]{2})([^/]+)\/(.*)$/\1[DATE]\/\4/;s/_\[DATE\]/[DATE]/' filename
```

**Output**

```
setenv run_area1 root/test1/[DATE]/dummy
setenv area2 root/test2/[DATE]/dummy
setenv run_area3 testRun/test1/blue[DATE]/dummy/
setenv area4 testRun/test2/[DATE]/thing2
```

<sub>**Note:** The `-E` option with `sed` enables extended regex, which if not supported, use the `-r` option.</sub>

Comment: FYI `-E` will work with OSX/BSD sed and newer versions of GNU sed so it's better than `-r` for portability. `-r` is only for GNU sed and is only required if you're using an older version that doesn't support `-E`.

Answer (score 0):

These can be tricky.

```bash
$ which sed ; sed --version | head -n1
/usr/bin/sed
sed (GNU sed) 4.9

$ echo 'happles' | sed 's/apple/***/'
h***s

## match s, if present:
$ echo 'happles' | sed 's/apple[s]/***/'
h***
```

Here, you might think "optional s", `[s]`, would match an `s`, if present (it does not):

```bash
$ echo 'http://example.com' | sed 's/http/***/'
***://example.com

$ echo 'http://example.com' | sed 's/http[s]/***/'
http://example.com
```

The correct approach, as suggested in Ed Morton's answer, is to allow 0 or 1 of the preceding expression, `{0,1}`:

```bash
$ echo 'http://example.com' | sed 's/http[s]\{0,1\}/***/'
***://example.com

$ echo 'https://example.com' | sed 's/http[s]/***/'
***://example.com
```

Variations:

```bash
## yes (sed and sed -e both require \-escaped curly braces):
$ echo 'http://example.com' | sed -e 's/http[s]\{0,1\}/***/'
***://example.com

## no (sed -e without \-escaping of curly braces):
$ echo 'http://example.com' | sed -e 's/http[s]{0,1}/***/'
http://example.com

##yes (sed -r doesn't require \-escaped curly braces):
$ echo 'http://example.com' | sed -r 's/http[s]{0,1}/***/'
***://example.com
```